# Saving User Agent to database avoiding SQL injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a action filter which I am using to track user activity. I'm also saving user agents to the database to see what devices my site is most commonly access through. My concern is SQL injection as if I use my browser to adjust my user agent I can inject sql. Does anyone have any idea how I could filter or validate these user agent strings?

```
ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
        {

            UserName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
            Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
            IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
            DateTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp,
            UserAgent = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent
        };
        db.AddToActionLogs(log);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework uses sql paramters, so basically you're pretty much protected against sql-injections (at leats in the code sample you supplied)